# Visual Studio, change Document Outline font size

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How can I change the font size of the Document Outline panel? I couldn't find it in Options->Fonts and Colours -> Show settings for.

---

**Why "Just change you system DPI" is a non-solution.**

Every single time when I ask for a way to customise font settings, there is someone that replies "just change the system DPI". I will show why that is not a solution. See the screenshot below. The left is Windows Notepad, and the right is LibreOffice Writer. This is on the same computer and on the same monitor. LibreOFfice's developers say that they are not to blame because they just follow the system standards, so they will not provide a way to change UI font size. But Windows has a long history and has lots of different historic UI frameworks in it. Obviously, Windows Notepad and LibreOffice are using different frameworks and following different standards. You cannot just change system DPI to make both of them look good. Unless all Windows apps follow the exact same font size for the same things, changing the system DPI is not a solution.

[image]

Comment: If that's a problem then the machine's monitor DPI setting is too low.

Comment: @HansPassant No, its font is smaller than other part like the menu. It is either using a relatively smaller font than the "Environment font" I have set, or disrespecting that setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible yet, but you can submit a feedback ticket to MS and recommend that it should be added. There is an option for `Environment -> Plain Text` but that changes the VS fonts in the menus, including **Solution Explorer**, but even though the panel is similar, **Document Outline** is not affected by this change.

Other workarounds include increasing the OS font scaling in the display settings, then decreasing everything else in VS, but it's not optimal. I am not sure if making your own theme might allow you to change this. You should look into this, but somehow I don't think it can be done this way either yet.

Comment: Oh well, if it is not possible, then I give up. I wonder why its font is smaller than other part of the UI. And system DPI change is not a solution for this kind of problem anytime I have this problem, because different apps use different font sizes. For example, the menu text size of UWP apps are already too large for me. My DPI is 200%. For the most part of Windows, I think 175% is good enough for me, but damn win32 dialogue font was too small, and it is still rather small with 200%. Actually, I am trying to move to Linux, because I have no hope MS would fix this anytime soon.

Comment: It might be a newer feature and therefore not integrated with the other panels. I still say that you should add feedback as they might consider to include it in the customization schemes :)